# How any contracts are deployed in upgradable smart contracts?

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts

I am very confused about the upgradable smart contracts , As some are saying that 2 contracts are deployed , some are saying 3 contracts a are deployed ? Can anyone please clear my doubt regarding this

I had done it using VS code and the 2 version of smart contract is deployed on the same address but am not able to view the changes ..

Answer (score 0):

A basic example is 3 contracts, each on different address.

1. Proxy
2. Implementation A
3. Implementation B

The Proxy contract points to Implementation A, and when you upgrade the contract, you change the pointer to the Implementation B.

---

If you deploy two `contract` classes on the same address, there's always one main contract that is deployed on this address, and the other is possibly its parent class, or is not deployed on that address at all.

```
// cannot deploy both on the same address
// either one is deployed on the address - or the other is

contract A {}
contract B {}
```

```
// A is parent of B
// if you deploy `A`, only its functions are available
// if you deploy `B`, its public functions as well as `A`'s public functions are available
// but it's still one instance of `B` (with `A` as a part of it) - there's no separate instance of `A`

contract A {}
contract B is A {}
```

Comment: And if i want to check the transactions where i can do it from ?

Comment: If the transactions are on a public network, you can search for the proxy address on a blockchain explorer - for example https://etherscan.io/ for mainnet Ethereum. If they're on a private network or emulator, that depends on the specific network if there's even a blockchain explorer... If there's no explorer, you can use the RPC methods or its wrappers to query transactions and transaction receipts by the transaction hash. For example the `eth_getTransactionReceipt` RPC method and its wrapper for ethers.js: https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider-getTransactionReceipt

Comment: ok ok thanks for clearing the doubt. It helps me alot.